# Jasmine spyOn function call inside function under test

Tags: jasmine

I am trying to use Jasmine to test the following function:

```
var Pdba = Class.create();
Pdba.prototype = {
      getChangeGroup: function(userId) {
      var query = 'active=true^u_change_group=true^u_organization=false^';
      var exGroup = new CompanyGroup();
      var groups = exGroup.getGroupsByQuery(userId, query); //want to spy/mock this call
      if (groups.next()) {
         return groups.sys_id.toString();
      }

      return '';
   }
type: 'Pdba'
};
```

I want to SpyOn the **getGroupsByQuery()** call, so that it doesn't make the actual call. Below is a collection of various things I have been trying, mostly just to see if I can "spy" and see that it has been called, then work on overriding so that I can replace the call with my own data.

```
describe('my suite of getChangeGroup tests', function() {
    var expPdba;
    var validUserId = 'user1';
    var expGrp;
    var ggbqMoc 

    beforeEach(function() {
        expPdba = new global.Pdba();
        coGrp = new CompanyGroup();
        spyOn(coGrp, 'getGroupsByQuery');
        ggbqMoc = jasmine.createSpy('getGroupsByQuery');
    });

    it('should return \'\' for empty userId', function() {
        coPdba.getChangeGroup('');

        expect(coGrp.getGroupsByQuery).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(ggbqMoc).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Is this possible or do I need to change the function under test to take a 'CompanyGroup' as a parameter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using jasmine v3. The syntax for creating a spy is pretty weird now- you have to pass a string that refers to the name of the variable you want to create a spy for, and then you pass an array of function names that should be spied on.

Try this:

```
describe('my suite of getChangeGroup tests', function() {
    var expPdba;
    var validUserId = 'user1';
    var expGrp;
    var spy; 

    beforeEach(function() {
        expPdba = new global.Pdba();
        coGrp = new CompanyGroup();
        spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('coGrp', ['getGroupsByQuery'])
    });

    it('should return \'\' for empty userId', function() {
        coPdba.getChangeGroup('');

        expect(coGrp.getGroupsByQuery).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```